# Passing multiple types to angular $location.search()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass an object having different data types to the $location service in angular. Here what works and what doesn't:

When I pass a normal array:

```
[
    key: "page",
    value: 1
],
[
    key: "color",
    value: "red"
]
```

And I use this code:

```
angular.forEach(myArray, function (data, index) {

  $location.search(data.key, data.value.toString());

});
```

I get expected URL : `abc.com?page=1&color=1`

When I pass an array along the previous data:

```
[
    key: "page",
    value: 1
],
[
    key: "color",
    value: "red"
],
[
    key: "names[]",
    value: ["jack", "steve", "mark", "larry"]
]
```

And I use this code:

```
angular.forEach(myArray, function (data, index) {
    if( typeof data.value === "object" ){
        var obj = {};
        obj[data.key] = data.value;
        $location.search(obj);
    }
    else{
        $location.search(data.key, data.value.toString());
    }
});
```

I get this:  `abc.com?name[]=jack&name[]=steve&name[]=mark&name[]=larry`

But I was expecting: `abc.com?name[]=jack&name[]=steve&name[]=mark&name[]=larry&?page=1&color=1`

Where did the `page` and `color` parameters go ?

Comment: Is it because you're overwriting `$location.search` for each item in `myArray` so only the last one in the array is showing?

Comment: In that case the 1st code wouldn't have worked the way it did.

Comment: In your first case and the `else` in the second case, you're providing a specific key to set, which will update just that one. If your data is an object, you seem to be replacing the whole `$location`.